# Jquery Displaying next items in a list

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have made a table list which displays which consists of a number of records. It currently shows a max of 10 each time. I have a button made which when clicked will show the next 10 records in the table. I am wondering how I can code this to make it work?

```
function showAll(qstring,qtype){
 $("#vsdiv").show();
 var myurl="scripts/searchadmin.php"; 
 $.ajax({
  url: myurl, dataType:'json',data:{querystring:qstring,querytype:qtype},
  success: function(member){
   $("#resultstable").append('<tr class="yellow">'+
                                        '<th>#REC</th><th>JOINED</th><th>USER NAME</th>'+
                                        '<th>CONTACT</th><th>ADDRESS</th><th>PHONE</th>'+
                                        '<th>EMAIL</th><th>STATUS</th><th>SELECT</th></tr>');
   var j=0;var totrecs=1;
   for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    $("#resultstable").append('<tr class="trow'+j+'">'+
                  '<td class="ids" id="z'+i+'">'+totrecs+'</td>'+
          '<td>'+member[i].jdate+'</td>'+
          '<td class="users"     id="username'+i+'">'+member[i].username+'</td>'+
          '<td id="contact'+i+'">'+member[i].fname+' '+member[i].lname+'</td>'+
          '<td id="myaddress'+i+'">'+member[i].address1+' '+member[i].town+'</td>'+
          '<td id="phone'+i+'">'+member[i].phone+'</td>'+
          '<td id="email'+i+'">'+member[i].email+'</td>'+
          '<td id="status'+i+'">'+member[i].status+'</td>'+
          '<td><input type="checkbox" name="whome" id="showMe'+i+'"'+
                                         'class="boxes" onclick="getMe('+i+')" /></td></tr>');  
                                         $('#sr').html('Showing 1 of '+member.length+' Members')

});


  totrecs++;
  j++;
 }
}
});
}
```

This is the current function which displays the first 10 records, how can I display the next set of 10 when I click the button? Any ideas?

Comment: Create a variable that stores the current offset of what's been requested from your server. Send that along with the request.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could achieve this would be to add range information to your query which might look something like this:

```
var rangestart = 0;
var rangeend = 9;
var rangeincrement = 10;
function showAll(qstring,qtype){
 $("#vsdiv").show();
 var myurl="scripts/searchadmin.php"; 
 $.ajax({
  url: myurl, dataType:'json',data:{querystring:qstring,querytype:qtype,rangestart:rangestart,rangeend:rangeend},
  success: function(member){
   $("#resultstable").append('<tr class="yellow">'+
                                        '<th>#REC</th><th>JOINED</th><th>USER NAME</th>'+
                                        '<th>CONTACT</th><th>ADDRESS</th><th>PHONE</th>'+
                                        '<th>EMAIL</th><th>STATUS</th><th>SELECT</th></tr>');
   var j=0;var totrecs=1;
   for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    $("#resultstable").append('<tr class="trow'+j+'">'+
                  '<td class="ids" id="z'+i+'">'+totrecs+'</td>'+
          '<td>'+member[i].jdate+'</td>'+
          '<td class="users"     id="username'+i+'">'+member[i].username+'</td>'+
          '<td id="contact'+i+'">'+member[i].fname+' '+member[i].lname+'</td>'+
          '<td id="myaddress'+i+'">'+member[i].address1+' '+member[i].town+'</td>'+
          '<td id="phone'+i+'">'+member[i].phone+'</td>'+
          '<td id="email'+i+'">'+member[i].email+'</td>'+
          '<td id="status'+i+'">'+member[i].status+'</td>'+
          '<td><input type="checkbox" name="whome" id="showMe'+i+'"'+
                                         'class="boxes" onclick="getMe('+i+')" /></td></tr>');  
                                         $('#sr').html('Showing 1 of '+member.length+' Members')

});


  totrecs++;
  j++;
 }
 rangestart += rangeincrement; // this assigns the new range start value
 rangeend += rangeincrement; // assign new range end value
}
});
}
```

Then your button just performs the same query again. You would also need to change your query on the server side to only return the range you require e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE xyz.somevalue = querystring LIMIT rangestart, rangeend;
```

That should get the result you are looking for.